# glossy or matte?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, resolution

I just bought a mint condition late 2011 MC721LL MacBook Pro which looks perfect, but I am curious about the display specs.  The screen has a low sheen matte look, but the resolution is 900 x 1440, so it is not the high resolution screen.. It also has the standard black surround, rather than the silver bezel.

I have owned other MacBooks with standard glossy screens, including a 2009, and this screen on the 2011 Macbook has a much lower sheen, but resolution specs are standard Macbook specs..  Seems odd.   Was there a matte option with the standard resolution display?

Answer (score 1):

From Everymac -

> The standard configuration of this model has an LED-backlit 15.4" widescreen TFT active-matrix "glossy" display (1440x900 native resolution), but it also was available via custom configuration with a "high-resolution glossy" 1680x1050 display and a "high-resolution antiglare" 1680x1050 display for an additional US$100 and US$150, respectively.

Ref : http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.0-15-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html

So, the answer would appear to be - 'No, there was no matte option at standard res 1440x900'

Comment: That is what I have also seen, but was trying to see if there were any other variations,  So, maybe a non reflective film was added to the screen, but it is not detectable to my eye

Comment: On that, I can't say... I'd hesitate to suggest picking at the edges with a fingernail/sharp implement to find out ;-)